# Push Notification Ionic. How to handle data of multiple notification?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, notifications

I have implemented a push notification on my ionic app using cordova push notification.

The whole Notification part is done. I receive notifications properly, but the problem is when I receive multiple notifications for eg.

If I have 3 notifications in ascending order

1. message1
2. message2
3. message3

And if I clicked on 1st notification which is 'message1'. Further app gets open and it shows me 'message3'.

No matter whichever notification I'll click, it always shows a last notification which was received.

I'm not getting how to catch a data of notification on which I had clicked

(Is it possible by local notification plugin? which has onclick function.)

PLEASE HELP